# How do I link the letters with the words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am creating a word game where you have to spell the words in the grid by dragging the letters in from the side.

This code randomly generates 12 words from the "listOfWords" and dynamically creates a 6x6 table. The words are also split into single characters **("m" "a" "t")** so draggable letters can be placed over to spell the words...

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", "pin", "gag", "sat", "pat", "tap", "sap", "tag", "gig", "gap", "nag", "sag", "gas", "pig", "dig", "got", "not", "top", "pop", "god", "mog", "cot", "cop", "cap", "cod", "kid", "kit", "get", "pet", "ten", "net", "pen", "peg", "met", "men", "mum", "run", "mug", "cup", "sun", "mud", "rim", "ram", "rat", "rip", "rag", "rug", "rot", "dad", "sad", "dim", "dip", "did", "mam", "map", "nip", "tin", "tan", "nap", "sit", "tip", "pip", "sip", "had", "him", "his", "hot", "hut", "hop", "hum", "hit", "hat", "has", "hug", "but", "big", "bet", "bad", "bad", "bed", "bud", "beg", "bug", "bun", "bus", "bat", "bit", "fit", "fin", "fun", "fig", "fan", "fat", "lap", "lot", "let", "leg", "lit"];

var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0).sort(function () {
return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0, 12);

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className='tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;


for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i += wordsPerRow) {
var row = document.createElement('tr');

for (var j=i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++ j) {
    var word = shuffledWords[j];

    for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++){
        var cell = document.createElement('td');


        cell.textContent = word[k];
        // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
}
tbl.appendChild(row);    
}

 document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Here is the code for the draggable letters that are dropped onto the grid to spell the words.

```
<div class="squares">

        <div id="drag1" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>a</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag2" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>b</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag3" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>c</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag4" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>d</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag5" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>e</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag6" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>f</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag7" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>g</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag8" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>h</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag9" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>i</p>
        </div>

         <div id="drag10" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>j</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag11" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>k</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag12" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>l</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag13" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>m</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag14" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>n</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag15" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>o</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag16" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>p</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag17" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>r</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag18" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>s</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag19" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style" tabindex="0">
        <p>t</p>
        </div>

        <div id="drag20" class="drag ui-widget-content box-style2" tabindex="0">
        <p>u</p>
        </div>
```

How do I make the words recognize the correct letters when they are dropped on top?

Something along these lines....

```
if ("mat" == drag13 + drag1 + drag19) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Step 1: Go here: http://jsfiddle.net/   Step 2: Create something that displays correctly. Step 3: Wait before posting the same type of question, and someone might help you, at least with a suggestion.

Comment: Something to consider would be to have a representation of the "grid" as rows and columns (and maybe diagonals too) rather than just a series of divs.  This way you could separate the logic for checking the grid contents from the drag event handler.  You could start with something basic like ("cat" == grid[i][j] + grid[i][j+1] + grid[i][j+2]) or make it better like (cat == grid.checkWord(i,j,"right"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it in the end...

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
    console.log($(event));
    console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

        $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('wordglow');
    }
    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");

        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");

        }
    }


},

activate: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    // try to remove the class
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3');
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.indexof(substring) it returns the index at which the substring starts in the string

ex:

```
if ('mat'.indexOf(drag13) != -1) { // -1 means substring is not in the string
  return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this should give a way to start, not enough? please be more specific.